# What's the meaning of QNetworkReply::ProtocolUnknownError?

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

I use a object of `QNetworkAccessManager` to post json data to a website.

when handle the reply which is a pointer of `QNetworkReply` class in the slot function, the value of `reply->error()` is `301` and the value of `reply->errorString()` is `Error downloading http://www.example.com/query - server replied: Service Unavailable`.

I check the documentation of `QNetworkReply`, the description of this error is:

> QNetworkReply::ProtocolUnknownError|301|the Network Access API cannot honor the request because the protocol is not known

and I also known this error is different form the http status 301.

and I have add `http://` before the url.

Can someone give some info about this?

Comment: Is that a GET, POST or PUT? Can you reach the server via curl etc.?

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld i use POST method. i send many same queries except params to that url, some of them reply rightly and some of them reply `301` error.

Comment: Could you please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) compliant example?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a 301 status code there's a redirect. In QtNetwork the ProtocolUnknownError is returned for redirects if the resolved URL is invalid[0] or does not use the http/https scheme[1]

Since I do not know what target-URL you get redirected to I cannot say for sure that this is what the problem is though.

[0] https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.15/src/network/access/qhttpnetworkconnection.cpp#L546
[1] https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.15/src/network/access/qhttpnetworkconnection.cpp#L563